# MAX function slowing the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

MAX function slowing the query. It is taking hours to bring the result back but when i run for an item it comes with 5 seconds. I am trying to run 1.6 millions records.Below is the code:

RDBMS: SQL SERVER

```
  `SELECT
   A.[GTIN]
  ,A.[Status]
      ,max(A.[Last_Changed_On]) as Last_Changed_On_OLD
  ,max(B.LastChangedOn) as Last_Changed_on_NEW
  ,(Case when (b.LastChangedOn is null) then Null else A.[Status] end) as 
    New_Status
  ,(Case when (b.LastChangedOn is not null) then Null else A.[Status] 
 end) as Old_Status

 FROM [PIMIDQ].[dbo].[Workflow_Status] A

 left Join 
              ( Select GTIN, 
              max(last_changed_on) as [LastChangedOn],
             [Status]
             from Workflow_Status
             group by
              GTIN,
              [Status]
               )  B  
              on  (A.Last_Changed_On = (B.LastChangedOn) and A.[Status] = 
B.[Status])
group by 
 A.[GTIN]
,A.[Status]
,(Case when (b.LastChangedOn is null) then Null else A.[Status] end)
,(Case when (b.LastChangedOn is not null) then Null else A.[Status] end)`
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can't really do much with this. We would need to see the execution plan. You can upload that [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). Also helpful would be the table definitions (including indexes) along with approximate row counts. Bonus points for posting sample data as text along with the desired output.

Comment: I am curious who thought this question was worthy of an upvote. While I don't like to just downvote questions, especially for new posters, this is not a good question as posted because it lacks the details needed to provide an answer.

Comment: Some information regarding indexes on the table etc would be useful or the query plan. Most likely a single item is doing a key lookup for the row's data vs the max doing a full index scan or worse a full table scan on the table.

Comment: how long does your sub query containing MAX take to run in isolation?  As far as I can see it is static to the rest of the query.

Comment: This query does not seem to be correct. Isn't join predicate missing `GTIN`? Why are you calling `Last_Changed_On` as `_old` or `_new` whereas this field from A and B cannot have different values (except NULL) since they are joined based of this field equality? Did you try yo use LEAD/LAG?

Comment: Aggregate function in sub queries used for joins generally is kind of bad for performance due to the fact it has to recalc per row. I would rewrite that all together. I mean its kind of a large table (ish), but I am certain writing to have that aggregate not in the join query will solve a big portion of your issue. Also, gotta love automotive data, gtins arent so bad but fitment is the worst!  (assumption there, forgive me if im wrong)

Comment: One problem I can see is the left join; the right-side (B) requires the entire table to be aggregated before it can determine the join condition B.LastChangedOn.  Also, realize that if you group with [status] then you aren't getting the "most recent status".  You're getting the most recent [LastChangedOn] date for whatever statuses were inserted into the table.

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes, i am trying to get lead and lag time sort of. I need both new and old date plus overall date in the query result.

Comment: @Cato The subquery is taking about 12 seconds to pull 1.56 millions records.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017